# HoughLines() - Drawing the lines and getting their position

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, real-time, hough-transform

Im new to openCv and image processing in general. I need to draw the lines and their position in real time from an camera input like this:
[image]

i already have the image from the canny edge detection, but when applying hough line and trying to draw it to that image using the following code i found:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
  Mat input;
  Mat HSV;
  Mat threshold;
  Mat CannyThresh;
  Mat HL;

 //video capture object to acquire webcam feed
 cv::VideoCapture capture;
 capture.open(0);
 capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
 capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

 //start an infinite loop where webcam feed is copied to cameraFeed matrix
 //all operations will be performed within this loop

 while (true){ 

    capture.read(input);
    cvtColor(input, HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //hsv
    inRange(HSV, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), threshold);//thershold
    MorphOps(threshold);//morph operations on threshold image
    Canny(threshold, CannyThresh, 100, 50); //canny edge detection

    std::vector<Vec4i> lines;
    HoughLines(CannyThresh, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 150, 0, 0 );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line( input, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    } 

    imshow("camera", input);
    waitKey(30);
    
  }
return 0;
}
```

i get the following exception:
[image]

1- I cant say i really understand that code yet, but can you tell me why it isnt working?.

2- if i manage to make it work, how can i get the Y coordinate of the horizontal lines? i need to know if another object is inside, below or above this one. so i need the position on the Y axis of the 2 horizontal lines on this image (the ones roughlines detected), so i can determine where the other object is regarding this "rectangle".

## EDIT #1

I copied the complete code. as you can see in the second image, the debugger doesn't throw any errors. but in the console of the program it says `OpenCV Error:Assertion failed (channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype)) in cv::Mat::copyTo, file C:\builds\master_packSlave-Win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp, line 281`. Also the last call in the call stack is this:  `>   KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16() Unknown`, im starting to thing is an opencv problem and not a code problem, maybe something with that dll.

## EDIT #2

i changed the line

```
 std::vector<Vec4i> lines; // this line causes exception
```

for

```
 std::vector<Vec2f> lines;
```

and now it enters the for loop. but it now gives another run time error (another segmentation fault. i think it has to do with these values:
[image]

i think they may be going off range, any ideas?

Comment: Use the debugger and get error message

Comment: edited with the debugger information.

Comment: You're probably using debug libs in release, or viceversa. Or libs compiled with another compiler, or architecture (x86 vs x64).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be the fact that you're trying to draw a line  as you had a 3-channel image (using `Scalar(b,g,r)`), but what you really have is a single-channel image (I suppose that `CannyThresh` is the output of [Canny()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny)).

You can try to change the image to a colored version, using something like this:

```
Mat colorCannyThresh = CannyThresh.clone();
cvtColor(colorCannyThresh, colorCannyThresh, CV_GRAY2BGR);
```

or you can draw a line using `Scalar([0~255])`, changing your `line()` call to:

```
line(CannyThresh, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255), 3, CV_AA);
```

Again, since it's not a complete code, I'm not sure this is the case, but it could be.

About Question2, what you mean by "Y coordinate of the horizontal lines?"

## Edit

After `inRange()`, `threshold` is a `Mat` of the same size as `HSV` and CV_8U type ([inRange()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange)), which means it is CV_8U*3 (3-channel -> H.S.V). Are you sure `threshold`, after `MorphOps()`, is CV_8U*1 (single-channel), as [Canny() expects](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny)?

If your goal is to find what is inside a rectangle, you might want to read about [minAreaRect()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#minarearect).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will check that. i edited the second question with more information

Comment: i tried what you said, but unfortunately it didn't work, any other idea?

Comment: edited with the debugger information, and complete code

Comment: @angel208 edited the answer. Could you also say at which line the program crashed?

Comment: just at the `for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )`, if i remove all that loop, the program works fine,  i can even show the canny image. Even if i comment everything inside the loop it crashes. again, the debugger doesn't throws any error, the problem is when i execute the program, its like a segmentation fault.